# Mod_rewrite rewrite example.com/page.php?v1=abc&v2=def to example.com/abc/def

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Using `Apache`'s `htaccess` file, I am trying to `rewrite` the URL `http://example.com/page.php?v1=abc&v2=def` to `http://example.com/abc/def`.

So far I have:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule case-study/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ /case-study.php?$1=$2&$3=$4
```

But this seems to just serve the actual file `page.php` with the URL unchanged.

Does anyone know what the proper way to do this or what might be wrong with the above?

Answer (score 3):

You have it backwards. What you're rewriting from goes first, then what you're changing it to goes at the end. The following may not be exact, but should be close to what you need:

`RewriteCond {%QUERY_STRING} ^v1=(.*)&`

`RewriteCond {%QUERY_STRING} v2=(.*)$`

`RewriteRule case-study.php /case-study/%1/%2/`

Here's the RewriteRule documentation for more details: [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

Note that the use of leading slashes on the rule and substitution will depend on the context you're using it in (see the linked documentation). In the above example, the %1 and %2 refer back to the capture groups in the first and second RewriteCond. Here's a page that describes that approach: [mod_rewrite based on query string parameters](http://statichtml.com/2010/mod-rewrite-baseon-on-query-string.html)

Comment: Thanks for this didn't know that. The URL still isn't changing however. htaccess is definitely being read as I can get it to 500 error with random text. Is there anything you could suggest as to why it's not rewriting?

Comment: Now that I think about it, I don't believe the query string is used within a RewriteRule, I think that has to go in a RewriteCond ahead of it ... I'm updating the answer - it may not be exactly correct (haven't done that type of rule in a while), but should be heading in the right direction.

Comment: Updated ... if that doesn't work as-is, you might want to start more simply - just match the base case-study.php and rewrite it to /case-study, for example. Once that rewrite works as expected, then tack on the query parameters one at a time. And, of course, always remember to restart the web server between tests so you don't fool yourself into a false conclusion after updating the files (spoken from experience).