# trouble with simple mod_rewrite redirect rule

Tags: .htaccess

I have mod_rewrite working in a development environment.
This testing domain is using these rules in an .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine on

 # deal with potential pre-rewrite spidered / bookmarked urls
RewriteRule ^clothes/index.php?pg=([0-9]+)$ /clothes/index$1.php [R=301,L] 

 # deal with actual urls
RewriteRule ^clothes/[0-9a-z-]+-pr([0-9]+).php$ /clothes/product.php?pid=$1 [L]
```

**The 2nd Rule works fine.**  Entering http ://testdomain.dev/clothes/shirt-pr32.php is silently  delivered content from  http ://testdomain.dev/clothes/product.php?pid=32  ...which is as desired and expected!

However, assuming this was applied to a live site, one that had originally used paths such as: http ://testdomain.dev/clothes/product.php?pid=32,  I'd like to redirect any incoming requests following the old pattern to the new urls  ...which is what **the 1st Rule was intended to do**.

My problem is my **testing server seems to ignore the 1st Rule** and serves the page as requested (page loads but address bar remains at http ://testdomain.dev/clothes/product.php?pid=32)

Any assistance or enlightenment would be most graciously accepted!

Answer (score 0):

You need to match the query string within a RewriteCond, then backreference that RewriteCond from the rule. The RewriteRule only matches against the path, not the query string.

Here's a related post I previously answered with a similar request: [Mod_rewrite rewrite example.com/page.php?v1=abc&v2=def to example.com/abc/def](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363132/mod-rewrite-rewrite-example-com-page-phpv1-abcv2-def-to-example-com-abc-def/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't match against the query string in a rewrite rule, you need to use the `%{QUERY_STRING} variable in a condition and use the **%** to backrefernce groupings. So instead of:

```
RewriteRule ^clothes/index.php?pg=([0-9]+)$ /clothes/index$1.php [R=301,L]
```

You'll need:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pg=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^clothes/index.php$ /clothes/index%1.php? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Ah, okay , i missed that! 
However, the above is not working correct either. With other rewrite rules removed and the .htaccess file now looking like this:
    `    Options +FollowSymLinks
    Options +Indexes
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pg=([0-9]+)
    RewriteRule ^clothes/index.php$ /clothes/index%1.php [R=301,L]
`
    I now get a server error regarding too many redirects. Sorry, i can't post this with formatting and line breaks.

Comment: @user1304362 sorry, forgot to add a `?` to the end of the rule's target to remove the query string