# Rewrite rules with query strings for subdomains with rootdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm not expert in .htaccess. I want to rewrite my news and blog url (with or without www) as:

bdnews24.com/reporter.php?u=Name
to-> bdnews24.com/Name

m.bdnews24.com/reporter.php?u=Name
to-> m.bdnews24.com/Name

img.bdnews24.com/image.php?id=791011.jpg
to-> img.bdnews24.com/791011.jpg

bdnews24.com/details.php?id=100200300
to-> bdnews24.com/100200300

My current .htaccess file is below, which is not working as I want it.
This catches all request URI and if not exist it will go to index.php?u=ANYTHING

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# AlegroCart REWRITES START
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: After adding the details of your .htaccess file, you should clarify the issue by giving an example URL that is not working, the URL you are expecting it to rewrite to, and the URL it is incorrectly rewriting to (or failing to rewrite). Here are a couple of links to a related post and a guide on query string rewriting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363132/mod-rewrite-rewrite-example-com-page-phpv1-abcv2-def-to-example-com-abc-def/ http://statichtml.com/2010/mod-rewrite-baseon-on-query-string.html

Comment: Options +FollowSymlinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

# AlegroCart REWRITES START
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This set of rules should do what you want, based on the information you've provided:

```
RewriteCond {%QUERY_STRING} ^u=(.*)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(m.|www.)?bdnews.com$
RewriteRule ^reporter.php /%1?

RewriteCond {%QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.*)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^img.bdnews.com$
RewriteRule ^image.php /%1?

RewriteCond {%QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.*)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(m.|www.)?bdnews.com$
RewriteRule ^details.php /%1?
```

First it matches the query string, then the host name(s), then rewrites the original query string (%1) into the new URL.

Comment: Thanks david for response. Carry on.