# htaccess - Redirecting based on variables

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have recently updated my site and as a result the old username system has changed and this has caused problems with links that are now on google.

I've experimented with htaccess to with no success but here's what I am trying to do:

```
http://example.com/userprofile.php?Member=[insertusername]
```

Needs to be redirected to:

```
http://example.com/user/[insertusername]
```

From what I have gathered htaccess seems to be the way to do this but of course I'd be just as grateful to hear any other options. Many Thanks.

Comment: From your wording, this is the opposite of a normal rewrite.  What does the end user see in his browser address bar in the final result? And do you need a silent internal rewrite or to forcibly redirect the browser?

Comment: Check out this related post to see how query strings can be used for the kind of rewrite that you want. My answer there should give you the idea of what to do - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415377/rewrite-rules-with-query-strings-for-subdomains-with-rootdomain/

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses. The idea was to do more of a forcible redirect rather than a silent rewrite as i'm trying to redirect links from the old system (userprofile.php?Member=*) to the new system (user/*). Thanks for the help.